# Check to see if one shape fits into another (2D plane)

Tags: jquery

Bashing my head against a wall.

So I have a set product shape (fixed width and length).

The user can then enter their custom shape size (width and length).

I then need to check that the user shape fits into the product length, note that I need to check if it fits horizontally or vertically.

So I am trying to write a statement that says:
 1. See if the user shape fits into the fixed shape
 2. if not rotate user shape by 90deg and check again
 3. if both of these fail, the shape does not fit, otherwise it does.

So here is what I have so far, but it gives me bizarre results

```
if( ( $itemW > $prodW ) || ( $itemL > $prodL ) ){
            if( ( $itemL > $prodW ) || ( $itemW > $prodL ) ){
                //console.log('I dont fit');
                $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', true);
                $('.does-it-fit').html('<div class="dinner">Unfortunately your drawing wont fit the sheet.</div>');
            } else {
                //console.log('I fit');
                $('.does-it-fit').html('');
                $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        } else {
            //console.log('I fit');
            $('.does-it-fit').html('');
            $('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the logic was sound.

The issue was the input... I needed to add parseInt( ); around the numbers.